# Google App Engine GWT Date serialization

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

I got following  error when serialize (java.util)Date field available in Object. My GWT version is 2.1.1 and APP engine SDk is 1.4.2.

Is Any one got any idea about this issue?

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeWithCustomSerializer(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:764)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:727)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:534)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:609)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:564)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:243)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeWithCustomSerializer(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:746)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.datanucleus.sco.simple.Date' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = Fri Mar 25 06:30:00 UTC 2011
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:614)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:534)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:704)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:734)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:45)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:38)
    ... 43 more
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to detach your JDO object on the server before sending it back to the client.

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPM();
pm.makePersistent(myObject);
return pm.detachCopy(myObject);
```

Comment: wow, that did the trick! I am really grateful for this hint - saved me lots of time!

Answer (score 2):

Judging by this line from the stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.datanucleus.sco.simple.Date' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = Fri Mar 25 06:30:00 UTC 2011
```

It sounds like your IDE has imported a version of `Date` other than the one you expected (which is `java.util.Date`). This happens to me all the time. Just change that erroneous import.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was Date object which return by JDO contents many unnecessary data. I have fixed it like this:

```
public Date getDate() {
    if(date!= null){
        long timeStamp = date.getTime();        
        return new Date(timeStamp);
    }           
    return null;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: I think the magic that happens here is that you converted your instance of `org.datanucleus.sco.simple.Date` into `java.util.Date`. The client side doesn't know the datanucleaus libraries, but it knows the standard Java classes.